# Unable to start activity in device

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.developerfeed.com/simple-quiz-game-andriod), but I'm getting this error message, when I run on my device:

```
   08-04 01:40:12.820  27896-27896/com.filipeferminiano.quiz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.filipeferminiano.quiz/com.filipeferminiano.quiz.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.filipeferminiano.quiz/databases/triviaQuiz
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You're trying to use a database object you've already closed.  Don't do that-  either don't close it in the first place or open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to replace this class,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions(db);
    }
    private void addQuestions(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        Question q1=new Question("Which company is the largest manufacturer" +
                " of network equipment?","HP", "IBM", "CISCO", "C");
        this.addQuestion(q1,db);
        Question q2=new Question("Which of the following is NOT " +
                "an operating system?", "SuSe", "BIOS", "DOS", "B");
        this.addQuestion(q2,db);
        Question q3=new Question("Which of the following is the fastest" +
                " writable memory?","RAM", "FLASH","Register","C");
        this.addQuestion(q3,db);
        Question q4=new Question("Which of the following device" +
                " regulates internet traffic?",    "Router", "Bridge", "Hub","A");
        this.addQuestion(q4,db);
        Question q5=new Question("Which of the following is NOT an" +
                " interpreted language?","Ruby","Python","BASIC","C");
        this.addQuestion(q5,db);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest,SQLiteDatabase db) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
// return quest list
        dbase.close();
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the trace already told u the reason why it crashed:
`attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase`

Answer (score 1):

check your database objects it closed some where in your code  also check in tutorial there are not anywhere write db.close() so do not close your data base in your example..
thats it...